# Visual Studio automatically renames external tool path

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to set some external tools paths in Visual Studio 2017 and for some reason, certain entries get automatically renamed. Under

```
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools
```

I am trying to enter `$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External` but after clicking [OK] on the Options dialog, this then gets renamed to `$(VSInstalledExternalTools)`.

I made a small MSBuild script to test the values of each of these variables. This included the following message statements:

```
    <Message Text="$(VSInstallDIR)\Web\External"></Message>
    <Message Text="$(VSInstalledExternalTools)"></Message>
```

The first one outputs "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External" whereas the second outputs an empty string. This is breaking my build process, but I cannot figure out how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Hard to say:

But please use `$(VSINSTALLDIR)Web\External` instead of `$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External`.

The latter one equals: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\\Web\External`

[image]

Line6: Result of `$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External` using `\\`

Line7: Result of `$(VSINSTALLDIR)Web\External`.

I think the `\\` causes this issue. Hope it helps.